# Почему урок - зубрят?

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а почему что-то механически заучивать - это зубрить? При чем тут, собственно, зубы или зазубрины?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря Шанского:

ЗУБРИТЬ - исконное слово из школьного арго, зубрить - это насекать зубцы (пилы и др.), однообразная, длительная работа, не требующая больших умственных усилий. Аналогично: долбить/зубрить и долбежка/зубрежка.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, потому что говорят: "чтобы от зубов отскакивало"